# 3TB RAID1 not detected in Hyper-V Core 2012

Tags: raid1, hyper-v-server-2012, diskpart

I'm creating a small server, but I have issues with one RAID config (RAID1-HOST-DATA).

As you can see in the image below, everything seems fine. My four physical disk are detected, and two RAID1 are created as expected.

[image: Screenshot of RAID configuration]

I installed a Hyper-V Server Core 2012 on the RAID1-HOST. However, the RAID1-HOST-DATA isn't detected when I run a DISKPART.

[image]

Why do I have this? I want to have my RAID1 of 2.7TB for my data, but it doesn't seem possible.

I did a lot of search before posting this, I hope someone could help me.

The server is a Dell Precision T5500. I ran BIOS update yesterday to be sure that it's not due to BIOS.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the Intel RAID driver installed on Windows?

https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?DwnldID=22194

That may be you issue here.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: What didn't work? Is the driver installed? Do you see the drives in windows at all? If not, are you booting in UEFI mode? Many motherboard don't support Intel raid in UEFI mode.

Comment: I wasn't able to install those drivers in Hyper-V Server Core 2012 r2. I need to find them before continuing. I'm quite sure the motherboard support the Intel Raid because my first RAID is seen when I do a diskpart (see original screenshot).

Comment: First screenshot shows Intel RAID in Option ROM driver, so it's ok
There are many Intel RAID drivers, they may vary according to your chipset as it is a chipset thing. try your luck here:
https://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&keyword=RAID+

Comment: It seems that Intel isn't supporting Hyper-V server... I tried with Windows Server 2012 R2, but not working. See this link https://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&FamilyId=42&ProductID=2101&ProdId=2101

Comment: No drivers are provided by Intel for Hyper-V Server Core 2012, so bottom line, I installed Windows Server 2012 R2 and now it's fine. I still feel disappointed that it wasn't working "out-of-box", even with a lot of effort to get it working.